# Local LWC - Proxy Issue

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, proxy

Just getting into LWC and local development, so bear with me.  Are there local LWC development proxy settings?  I have been looking for a bit, but can't find anything.  Basically, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:3333/services/data/v47.0/ui-api/records/a2I4F000000ai15UAA?
```

I thought I had all the proxy settings I needed between environment variables, VS Code settings, .npmrc, etc...

My code works when I deploy it to my org and when I'm at home.  But locally at work behind proxy, I'm getting that error.

Snippet:

```
let recordToUpdate = generateRecordInputForUpdate({
    apiName: 'Donation__c',
    //id: this.recordId,
    id: 'a2I4F000000ai15UAA',
    fields: resetFields            
});

updateRecord(recordToUpdate)
    .then( result => { 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)); 
    })
    .catch( error => { 
        console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)); 
    });
```

Thanks in advance!